# After upgrading my VPN from 20.04 to 22,04, I at times get the following desktop and clicks on it do not work. Any idea how to fix it?

Tags: 22.04, vpn, desktop-environments

Here is a screenshot of what I get:
[image]

I tried rebooting (warm and cold boots) and quite often I get the same result. What could create this issue? Would there be ways to fix it?

My take is that it completely misinterpret the 200% setting (which I need because I have 4K monitor and everything is too small without it).

Oh and I can't run anything because clicking on windows / resizing doesn't work. As if the desktop was totally preventing such from happening. Really weird state.

Another thing, I have 4 screens and when I go to another one with Cmd-F1, Cmd-F2, etc. I actually see the full desktop as expected for a split second.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution. It's not ideal, but at least it keeps me going.

I think that the issue is that the desktop area uses the "old" (default) resolution of 800x600 because somehow it's not able to use the correct resolution in the login screen after a reboot.

Killing the gnome shell and login back in saved the day for me:

```
sudo killall -QUIT gnome-shell
```

In my case, after that command, the login screen came back with the correct resolution.

Since in that situation I can't really do anything on my screen, there is no need to warn you to save your data before running that command. However, if your situation is different, that's your warning. It is likely to kill all your user's processes whether you saved your data or not.